# NavigationDrawer with Background image

Tags: java, android

I want to have an image in the background of the drawer **behind the menu**. In this piece of code the **image is in front of the menu**. Im not sure, but I cannot use a FrameLayout in this particular case.

The image should also **maintain its aspect ratio** and the **semitransparent color** should stay in front of it. This color is provided by the @color/menuSemi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:background="@color/menuSemi"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        style="@style/AppTheme.navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_bg"
                android:src="@drawable/sidebar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: Result of this markup]

Comment: I would use a FrameLayout: A container for the background and in front a container for the content instead of using menu attribute try a custom layout in the front container

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put your `NavigationView` in `RelativeLayout` and set the `RelativeLayout` `gravity "start"` and add `ImageView` inside the `Relativelayout` as first element.

And, Set NavigationView Background transparent

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/sidebar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    style="@style/AppTheme.navigation"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

So,your layout now looks like:-

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_bg"
                android:src="@drawable/sidebar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:background="@color/menuSemi"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        style="@style/AppTheme.navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set the background as a new ImageView. You should rather put it as the `background` of the NavigationView.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sidebar"
    ...
```

Comment: Two problems here:
1: image stretches (does not maintain aspect ratio)
2: Cannot set semitransparent color in front of it

Answer (score 0):

Put the image as background

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sidebar"
```

and **don't** set

layout_width and layout_height as wrap content or match parent.

or have a navigation header file seperately:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img_header_bg"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      />
```

...

Answer (score 0):

In your NavigationView Just Change your Background Color

```
android:background="@color/menuSemi"
```

To Background Drawable

```
android:background="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"
```

To Make Image Semi transparent use following code in your activity.

```
YOUR_NAVIGATION_VIEW.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
```